# WAMP - website display incorrectly

Tags: html, apache, web, wamp

I apologize for my poor English since it's not my mother lang.

I'm a newbie in web development. When I open my HTML page by clicking index.html, everything shows up correctly in my browser. But when I open via [http://localhost/SOME_DIR/SOME_DIR/index.html], the browser only shows some [div] frames and plain text. My CSS style and pics are all missing.

In WAMP, I've checked the Localhost and phpinfo() pages, both OK.

Maybe I need to open certain Apache services?

I don't know where goes wrong.

Comment: may be there is some referencing with file:///, can you post the code

Comment: So the path to the CSS and images is wrong, what path are you using for the image src and CSS?

Comment: I'm using absolute path, included in [base] section. But when I open the page locally, everything shows up correctly. Why not working on the Apache?

Comment: What path have you specified in `<base>`? (I recommend avoiding `<base>` it is usually more trouble then just having sensible relative URLs)

Comment: <base href="C:/wamp/www/StrangeAttractor/" target="_blank">

Comment: if you have a css folder within the StrangeAttractor then you should just put the href as "css/main.css" (or whatever name is your css). Same goes for the images folder

Comment: @Pete D Solved! Thank all the geeks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<base href="C:/wamp/www/StrangeAttractor/" target="_blank">
```

should be

```
<base href="/StrangeAttractor/" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the site over HTTP but you are trying to set the `<base href>` to your local disk. There are two problems with this:

1. You are using a plain file path but you have to specify the scheme (`file://`) in order to switch protocol
2. Security restrictions limit what resources web pages served over the network are allowed to load from the local disk

The solution: Load **all** your content over HTTP.